# numerical approximation 2D integral

Tags: numeric, integral

I want to approximate numerically integral in the 2 D rectangular domain.

D = [0, 10] X [0, 10]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ycS6.png)

I know we can approximate integral with a double sum for x and y. We need to divide domain my subdomains.
x bar and y bar are the values in the center of each subdomain.

My function is represented numerically.
I know my value of function f(x, y) for every pair (x, y), but  I don't know how to find function values in pair (x bar and y bar)

```
x1, x2 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 10, 100),np.linspace(0, 10, res))
xx = np.vstack([x1.ravel(), x2.ravel()]).T
f = KL._eigenfunctions[0](xx) #this is just the class KL that can find the value of function
```

This is how my function looks like in 2 D domain: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poOYR.png)